# Read entries from text file as column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a text file which has 1000 rows/entries. These 1000 entries correspond to the column names  for my dataframe. These are the  new features that need to be added to the dataframe  for  model development.
My input text file looks like this:

```
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8
```

I was looking to automatically create a dataframe that reads all these lines from the text file as a column name ? Is there a wayI could read the lines from the text file as individual features and put as a dataframe?
Expected  output

```
Newdataframe_df2 = withtext_df[['show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3', 
'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4', 
'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3', 
'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8' ]
```

Can pd.read csv be used such that  so that text file entries can be imported as a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8"""

# note that StringIO will be replaced with the file path
# then just read_csv and transpose the frame after setting header to none and index to col 0
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, index_col=0).T

print(df.columns)

Index(['show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3',
       'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2',
       'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4',
       'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2',
       'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2',
       'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3',
       'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1',
       'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11',
       'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10',
       'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10',
       'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11',
       'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8'],
      dtype='object', name=0)
```